# Funny behavior in firefox hover on div

Tags: css, firefox, html, hover

**Problem solved, thanks everybody**

Here's the problem

I have something like this

```
<a href='http://google.com' class="buy_now" > 
    <div class='yada yada' > Go </div> 
</a>
```

`buy_now` has `background-color` on `:hover`

In chrome it works but in firefox, while hovering, it keeps flashing / blinking etc

Is there anything wrong with my code or this is a firefox bug?

Here's the live demo: http://duskblue.org/firefox_bug.html

**Edit:** ok, seems to be a transitory problem here, works fine after restarting firefox. :/ (3.5.9) here.

**Edit 2:** demo is now valid HTML according to validator.w3.org

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 and could not duplicate this behavior. Maybe it is a bug in a specific build?

Comment: Well, I don't see the problem in FF with your example...

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. (FF 3.6.3)

What version of firefox are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Might there be a firefox plugin you've installed that's interfering with your code?

I can't reproduce the error you're reporting in any browser, using the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here (Firefox 3.5.9).

Bear in mind that this isn't valid HTML/XHTML, all bets are off.

Your best be would be to make sure that the `<div>` as exactly the same height/width as the surrounding `<a>`.

Comment: Yes, it's true, this has been cut-paste from production code for example purposes so a lot of things are off

I'll try making the div the same size as the a

Answer (score -1):

when debugging stuff like this I always like to have valid html - which is this isn't